# How to install rpcbind?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation

```
$ lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
  Release:  16.04
  Codename: xenial
$ sudo apt-get install rpcbind
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Package rpcbind is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

  E: Package 'rpcbind' has no installation candidate
$ sudo apt search rpcbind
  [sudo] password for mohet01: 
  Sorting... Done
  Full Text Search... Done
```

---

How to install `rpcbind`?

Comment: @Rinzwind Query edited. How to enable "security" repo from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `rpcbind` is available on the [`main`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/rpcbind/download) repository.

You should enable the repository on your sources.list through the command:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

A sample `sources.list` ([see the manpage for more details](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/sources.list.5.html)):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
```

Save then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rpcbind
```